# Getting API response time with python request

Tags: python, python-requests

Beginner requests user here. I am attempting to create automation code that allows me to do API testing and I want to grab the response timing with python requests. How can I do this accurately?

Before I was using the code

```
start = time.time()
category_response = requests.get('https://wralarchives.com/api/landing-page/get-category-totals')
roundtrip = time.time() - start
roundtrip = round(roundtrip, 3)

print('\nResponse time is ' + str(roundtrip))
assert roundtrip < .5
```

But this seems to return a response time that is much longer than what is shown on the inspect page (889ms instead of ~50-75ms) Why is this?

Comment: I suggest to do `cProfile.run("<the requests function here>", sort="tottime")` and see where the function spends the most time. According to my stats, the majority is spend in SSL handshaking.